# I wanted to display an image whenever I pressed a button into a label widget inside a function

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk , Image

def addCards():
    img = Image.open("widgetClass\poker2.png")
    img = img.resize((50 , 70) , Image.ADAPTIVE)
    imgTest = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

    cards = tk.Label(
        master=frame,
        image=imgTest
    )

    cards.place(x = 20 , y=50)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Display images")
root.geometry("400x400")
root.resizable(False , False)

frame = tk.Frame(borderwidth=2 , height=100 , highlightbackground="red" , highlightthickness=2)
frame_b = tk.Frame(borderwidth=2 , height=100 , highlightbackground="red" , highlightthickness=2)

label = tk.Label(frame , text="Picture demo")
button = tk.Button(frame_b , text="Add cards" , command=addCards)


frame.pack(fill=X)
frame_b.pack(fill=X)
label.place(x=0 , y=0)
button.place(x=0 , y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I am trying to display an image using the addCard() function , but it just display an empty label. I am expecting whenever I pressed the add card button , there is an image pop out at the first frame , but no image was display unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am expecting whenever I pressed the add card button , there is an
> image pop out at the first frame , but no image was display
> unfortunately.

The problem can be fixed.
On line 20:
Change this:

```
cards.place(x = 20 , y=50)
```

to:

```
cards.place(x = 2, y=20
```

Add this on line 21:

```
def addCards():
     .
     .
     .
     
        
    cards.place(x = 2, y=20)
    cards.image = imgTest #<== Add this.
```

Screenshot:

[image]